# How to put a condition to check if the game of tic tac toe is tied in python?

Tags: python

I have tried a lot but just cant get my mind around how to check if the game of tic tac toe is tied.
Its a code in python.I am a beginnerso please explain in detail what should be done i am all ears.
Can i also get an idea of how to make the game single player.It would be really fun
I request anyone who can help me to please take look.
Thank you

```
import os
import sys
game=[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]

def print_game():
    os.system('cls')
    print(game[0]+" | "+game[1]+"| "+game[2])
    print("__|__|__")
    print(game[3]+" | "+game[4]+"| "+game[5])
    print("__|__|__")
    print(game[6]+" | "+game[7]+"| "+game[8])
    print("  |  |  ")


def player(p):

    print("Choose an empty space from 1-9")
    t=int(input())
    if game[t-1]!=' ':
        print("space not empty")
        player(p)
    else:
        game[t-1]=p        
        print_game()

def check_result(p1,p2,p3):
    value=6
    for i in range(8):
        if game[i]==" ":
            game[i]=6

    solution1=list(set((game[0],game[4],game[8])))
    solution2=list(set((game[0],game[3],game[6])))
    solution3=list(set((game[1],game[4],game[7])))
    solution4=list(set((game[3],game[4],game[5])))
    solution5=list(set((game[2],game[5],game[8])))
    solution6=list(set((game[2],game[4],game[6])))
    solution7=list(set((game[6],game[7],game[8])))
    solution8=list(set((game[0],game[1],game[2])))
    result=[solution1,solution2,solution3,solution4,solution5,solution6,solution7,solution8]
    for i in range(8):
        if len(result[i])==1 and result[i][0]!=6:
            if result[1][0]==p1:
                print("Player 1 wins!")
            elif result[1][0]==p2:
                print("Player 2 wins!")


    value=5


    for i in range(8):
        if game[i]==6:
            game[i]=" "
    if value==5:
            return 1
    else:
        return 2

def begin():
    n=2
    print("Press 1 for player1='X' and player2='O'\n Press 2 for player1='O' and player2='X'")
    tr=int(input())
    if tr==1:
        player1="X"
        player2="O"
    else:
        player1="O"
        player2="X"
    while True:
        print("Player 1's turn")
        player(player1)
        n=check_result(player1,player2,player3)
        if n==1:
            sys.exit()
        print("Player 2's turn")
        player(player2)
        n=check_result(player1,player2)
        if n==1:
            sys.exit()
        else:

print("The pattern of tic tac toe board is:-")
print("1 |2 |3 ")
print("__|__|__")
print("4 |5 |6 ") 
print("__|__|__")
print("7 |8 |9 ")       
begin()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your list if a null or " " exist if no null then end game

```
game=["x","x","x"," ","x","x","x","x","x"]


def isFinish():
    for i in game:
        if(i==" "):
            return "NO"

if(isFinish() == "NO"):
    print("GAME NOT OVER")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")
```

If you want single player you can use random module.
and random an int from 1-9

```
import random
print random.randint(0, 9)
```

output

```
This will output either 1, 2, 3 ... 9
```

You can check here:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/random/how-to-use-the-random-module-in-python

Comment: actually i want to put conditon such that when the game is tied it wil stop and display the game is tied
because my code doesnt stop when its tied

Comment: you can check your list if null or " " exist then the game is not finish else game finish try this : game=["x","x","x"," ","x","x","x","x","x"]


def isFinish():
    for i in game:
        if(i==" "):
            return "NO"
       
if(isFinish() == "NO"):
    print("GAME NOT OVER")
else:
    print("GAME OVER")